# What should I do with my wood countertop edge strips, in preparation for laminate installation

Tags: installation, kitchen-counters, nails, laminate

I'm planning on replacing the laminate sheet on my kitchen countertops. I plan to use Formica, and their [IdealEdge](https://www.formica.com/en-us/campaigns/idealedge-decorative-edging) edging for the sides. These laminate edges are kinda precision, with the goal being an extremely small gap between the laminate on the top vs the sides of the countertop, for visual appeal.

Part of the installation instructions for the edgings says to use a router to remove 1/4" of the countertop wood strips (not sure what those strips are called, see the pic) in order to get a nice flat 90 degree surface, so the edging strip will align cleanly.

Here's a pic of my countertop:

[image]

As you can see, my 2 wood strips around the edges have nails holding them on, and my router will cut their heads off when I remove the 1/4" of wood.

**My question**: What is a good way to proceed and deal with the nail issue?

I was thinking maybe I could replace the nails with screws, but drill a shouldered hole into the wood, so the screw head can sink below the surface maybe about 3/8", allowing me to router off 1/4" without hitting the screws. And I suppose I could remove the nails with pliers, although I may need to dig some wood out around each nail in order to grab it.

This method would allow me to keep the existing wood strips, which saves me time.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question in sentence format.

Comment: Looks like your countertop needs some prep work. You won't have a good outcome with the gaps in the parts and loose boards. None of it should be done with nails.

Comment: Also, you only need to remove enough material to straighten the edge, not an arbitrary 1/4". That's a _lot_ of wood to remove with a router for no good reason.

Comment: I'd start by ripping all that edging off, then putting it back firm & straight, using PVA & deeply countersunk screws. Apart from anything else it looks like it will be good practise for the 'IdealEdge' ..which looks anything but easy to get right first time.

Comment: Those edges look coved or curved not at a 90 but that could be my phone, I have done over a hundred Formica tops and that edge would concern me. Do they have special bits to finish the edge material or is it pre curved?

Comment: @Tetsujin what is PVA?

Comment: @EdBeal it's the picture, they look square in person. To cut the idealedge corners they recommend a miter saw to get close, then dry fit + sneak up on final dimensions via a mitered disc sander.

Comment: goat - PVA [Polyvinyl acetate] is the same glue you bought to stick your 'IdealEdge' on with, as per the instruction video.